# Ending a svg path drawing in FabricJs using right mouse click

Tags: onclick, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric JS version 4.5.0 working on a draw application.
I want to use the right mouse click to end the brush drawing but cannot achieve this.

please take a look at [this codepen snippet (credits to michaelsboost)](https://codepen.io/michaelsboost/pen/zYdgeNY) I am doing something similar to it.

```
if (tool.toString().toLowerCase() === 'pencil') {
    changeObjectSelection(false);
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush = new fabric.PencilBrush(canvas);
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.strokeLineCap = $('#brushStrokeCap').val(); // butt / round / square
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.strokeLineJoin = $('#brushStrokeLineJoin').val(); // bevel / round / miter
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.strokeMiterLimit = $('#brushMiter').val();
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 1;
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = strokePickr.getColor().toRGBA().toString();
    canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
  }
```

what changes need to be added there to use left mouse click and right mouse click interchangebly to end a svg path drawing?

- currently, if you select the pencil tool, clicked using your left mouse button it starts the drawing.
- If you right clicked it opens a menu, select copy image, and move your mouse.
- Undesired behaviour: try to left click, the whole drawing disappears.
- Desired behaviour: right mouse click should end the drawing as a svg on canvas.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get a reference to the canvas element
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
        // Add a rectangle to the canvas
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            fill: 'green',
            width: 100,
            height: 100
        });
        canvas.add(rect);

        document.onclick = hideMenu;
        document.oncontextmenu = rightClick;

        function hideMenu() {
            document.getElementById("contextMenu").style.display = "none"
        }
        function rightClick(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var menu = document.getElementById("contextMenu")
            menu.style.display = 'block';
            menu.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
            menu.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
        }
```

```css
    .context-menu {
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            background: lightgray;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .context-menu ul {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            min-width: 150px;
            list-style: none;
        }

        .context-menu ul li {
            padding-bottom: 7px;
            padding-top: 7px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .context-menu ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
        }

        .context-menu ul li:hover {
            background: darkgray;
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1920px" height="1080px"></canvas>
    <div id="contextMenu" class="context-menu" style="display:none">
        <ul>
            <li onclick="canvas.isDrawingMode = true">Drawing mode true</li>
            <li onclick="canvas.isDrawingMode = false">Drawing mode false</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```